# How to Convert string in html? (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have some code like

```
@{
      string result = "<div> text </div><br />";
}
```

and I want print content of this variable into some html

```
<div id="seachResult2">
   Search results: @Server.HtmlDecode(result);
</div>
```

but it doesn't work. I know about HtmlString class and it has ToHtmlString and ToString methods but I can't find something like string.ToHtml().

It is my first question here. I hope somebody will help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Does `@Html.Raw(result)` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use: `@Html.Raw(result)`

Or use an [`MvcHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx) instead of the normal string.